# How to clone an older GIT commit

Tags: git, clone

I'm a developer in training, with some spare time on my hands. I am trying to re-continue a discontinued project, and I don't have access to the repository besides read-only access, as I don't own it. I need to get a copy of an older snapshot of it, because it was the last stable one.

Am I missing something? Right now I can only get the latest version by "git clone xxx.git"
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

`git clone` is downloading the entire history, not just the latest version. Try `git log` to get the list of revisions, then `git checkout [SOME REVISION]` to rewrite your working tree to that commit

Comment: Thank you so much, now to get Maven and Eclipse fired up ^.^

Answer (score 1):

When using clone your taking the entire repository and its history (so all commit versions). So after clone, you can then just checkout whichever historical version you are looking to work from.

i.e. `git checkout -b branchName branchHash`